# Syntax for opening a report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am getting a Runtime 2465 error message trying to open a report using the following routine:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptSprechi", acViewPreview, , [qry_rptsprechi].[WasteType] = "UE", acIcon
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fourth argument (*WhereCondition*) is supposed to be a string value.  Yours looks wrong to me.

Try it this way ...

```vb
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptSprechi", acViewPreview, , "[WasteType] = 'UE'", acIcon
```

Comment: HansUp once again saving the day :)